# What is the purpose of the "Number of blobs to return from the trigger" setting on the "when a blob is added or modified" Logic App trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

The question is in the title however its not as clear cut as you may initially imagine.

From what I can tell a logic app is triggered once per blob regardless of what you set "Number of blobs to return from the trigger" to..

It does return a number of values called List of...  but again they seem to be badly named single values with no way to enumerate them.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/)  offer no insight whatsoever.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it's because the `SplitOn` is enabled by default. If this is enabled the triggerbody won't be a blob metadata array, it splits the array then each run it process one blob metadata.

If you want to use For each action, just disable the `Spliton`, or you could just do the actions without For each action.

[image]

Comment: Ah right  that makes sense.  I don't think that the "number of blobs to return..." setting has any effect when "split on" is enabled.